# How to add Active class in menu using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add Class in active menu in wordpress. I have use below Code. but it's not working please help me

```
                  wp_nav_menu( array(

                        'container' => '',
                        'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                        'theme_location' => 'primary'

                    ) );
```

Comment: Wordpress by default provide **current_page_item** in active class on menu please check in you wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php file

Comment: Yes but it's coming in <li> not in href link

Comment: Yes i have try your answer

Comment: is that work for you ?

Comment: I have add your code but it's not workin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this code in your nav-menu-template.php file in line number near about 149.

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="'.$classes[0].'" >';
```

Now on this case your css class apply to href link and you want to just add this class in admin side menu css classes.

let me know once done.

Comment: Have you any other idea for add classs

Comment: can you add css menu class in wordpress admin ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to functions.php

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
             $classes[] = 'active ';
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) for further reading

Comment: I have need to in href link .This is work in <li> not in href link

Comment: You'll need to write your own [Custom Walker Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)

Comment: Yes i have need to write own function

Answer (score 0):

please add this code in your nav-menu-template.php file in line number near about 149.

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="'.$classes[7].'">';
```

before add this code it will look like this

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

after add this code it will look like this

```
<a class="current_page_item" href="www.gooole.com">Home</a>
```

on that your `<li>` current class is display on link menu item class